# How to import bootstrap scss using scssphp?

Tags: php, css, sass

I am trying to import bootstrap.scss and compile everything in it. I am able ti import a single scss file but not every scss file.

http://leafo.github.io/scssphp/docs/

How can the below syntax be modified to import all scss files in bootstrap ?

```
    use Leafo\ScssPhp\Compiler;

$scss = new Compiler();
$scss->setImportPaths('assets/stylesheets/');

// will search for 'assets/stylesheets/mixins.scss'
echo $scss->compile('@import "mixins.scss";');
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is

```
$compiledcss = $scss->compile('@import "bootstrap.scss";');
```

This will import other scss files automatically.